# Javascript Client Side Include not injecting on Onclick Event

Tags: javascript

I am working on javascript client include and I'm using this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
        i;
    for (i in elements) {
        if (elements[i].hasAttribute && elements[i].hasAttribute('data-include')) {
            fragment(elements[i], elements[i].getAttribute('data-include'));
        }
    }
    function fragment(el, url) {
        var localTest = /^(?:file):/,
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            status = 0;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            /* if we are on a local protocol, and we have response text, we'll assume
 *                  things were sucessful */
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                status = xmlhttp.status;
            }
            if (localTest.test(location.href) && xmlhttp.responseText) {
                status = 200;
            }
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && status == 200) {
                el.outerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        try { 
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        } catch(err) {
            /* todo catch error */
        }
    }
}
```

This above code works really well when the page loads to include external .html files, using the following syntax:

```
<div id="myid" data-include="templates/myExternalTemplate.html"></div>
```

The above template will be loaded into the page.

My problem comes when I try to change the template from one to the other using an onclick event:

```
<div onclick="changeTemplate();"></div>
```

I have tried:

```
function changeTemplate() {
document.getElementById("myid").setAttribute("data-include","templates/2.html");
}
```

The above function is returning the following error:

```
*TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null*
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to give your div an id.

```
<div id="myId" data-include="templates/myExternalTemplate.html"></div>
```

Also, your `function` keyword should not be capitalized:

```
function changeTemplate() {
    document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute("data-include","templates/2.html");
}
```

Comment: The capitalized `Function` must have been a copying error, or the function never would have run and gotten the error.

Comment: @Satch3000 If the element has an ID, you wouldn't get an error saying that `getElementById` is returning `null`.

Comment: Does it have the ID in the template? You're replacing the whole element when you set `outerHTML`, so it gets the ID from the returned HTML.

Comment: That's clearly the problem. When you use `outerHTML` you lose the IDs, so you can't refer to those IDs afterward.

Comment: You need to fix the template files so they have the same IDs as the original HTML.